# iPhone forcing redraw (Objective C++)

Tags: iphone, pthreads, objective-c++

I'm coding this app in objective c++ (.mm file), and I'm having some difficulties. I have this loop, and every 10 seconds it runs and updates some numbers which I output to label fields on the display. The problem is that, although the loop works properly with the 10 second pause between runs (which I implemented with pthreads and a sleep function in an linked C++ file), the display will not refresh to show these new values. Is there a way I can force it to refresh/redraw at the end of every loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a

```
[ CATransaction flush ];
```

in the main UI thread after updating the labels.  You should only be updating the UILabel in the main UI thread as well, not the sleeping thread.  Sleeping the main UI thread will freeze the UI and possibly get your app killed by the OS watchdog.

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the value of the label at the end of each loop?

```
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New Value Is: %@", someOtherString]];
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing it with self.labelName.text = @"text here"